# How to efficiently join 2 DateFrames based on Timestamp difference?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two DataFrames with two different time-series data. For simplicity let's call them `Events` and `Status`.

```
events:
root
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- event_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id: string (nullable = true)

statuses:
root
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field3: string (nullable = true)
```

I'd like to join them so every `Event` will have a column of `list_statuses` that contains all `Row` objects of statuses in the previous X hours of its own timestamp.

I can do it by a cartesian product of `events` and `statuses` and then `filter` for the time criteria but that it (extremely) inefficient.

Is there any better way to do it? Anything off-the-shelf?

(I thought to group both dataframes on a time-window, then self-join the second to contain both the current and the previous time-windows and then join between them and filter, but if there is anything ready and bug-free,  I'd happily use...)

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Almost 2 months later but I thought it might help others if I post something I got to:

http://zachmoshe.com/2016/09/26/efficient-range-joins-with-spark.html

It basically a more efficient implementation of range-join between two DataSets based on a Timestamp or a Numeric field (Scala, with Spark 2.0).